# Communication between location service and Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, communication

there's a service class to update location, like lat and lng. What I want to do is pass the location to the Activity as soon as service getting result.
Here are few tries I made:

1. Broadcast receiver.
   It's very slow, I need to draw Activity based on location data, from self experience, it takes nearly half minute from service get last known location data to Activity receive broadcast signal.
2. Callback.
   It's much better, but it's still hard to attain "as soon as".

Could you please give me some advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is using interfaces. Because interface will notify main activity as soon as servicgot new result.

Comment: Could you please give me some instruction about how to do so? I am not familiar with these, thank you!

Comment: Currently i m not on my system. I m on mobile, but i will post some example of using interfaces.

Comment: Best example of interfaces is Button click listener. Click listener will not trigger until we click on button.

Comment: You mean use callback? But I only can find examples about how to set callback to let activity access to values in service, not to get values like trigger, so I am confused about this.

Comment: Just call interface method when you got new lat lon. And on main activity implement that interface. And you will receive new values in main activity when service got new lat lon.

Comment: How can main activity get to know new value? I mean, is there anything like trigger or something? Sorry I am not very familiar with interface..

Comment: In your interface make a method with two parameters lat and lon. And when u implement this interface in main activity then u also have to override method of interface. And in service pass value to method of interface and u will get new values in activity in that method.

Comment: First learn about communication between two fragments on android developer. You will get answers of all questions. (I tols about fragments because in fragments interfaces are used)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123127/discussion-between-lunars-and-pawneshwer-gupta).

Comment: I make an interface A with method B(lat, lng), and in service I get an instance of it like A a = new A(){B(lat, lng)}; and use a.B(lat, lng), finally make activity implement A and override B as B(lat, lng){Log.i(a,b)}; But I never receive log, is there anything wrong? Thank you!